# How to read a special String in the contents of a PDF file with PDFBox

Tags: java

I want to write a program to extract the topics, authors, abstracts and other information in the paper.Can pdfbox do that?And what am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have add pdfbox jar to your project, below is the code for you to retrieve some of the basic document attribute for PDF

```
import java.io.File; 
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument; 
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocumentInformation;

    public class readPdf {
       public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

          //Loading an existing document 

          File file = new File("C:/Users/user1/Desktop/test.pdf");

          PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file);
          //Getting the PDDocumentInformation object
          PDDocumentInformation pdd = document.getDocumentInformation();

          //Retrieving the info of a PDF document
          System.out.println("Author of the document is :"+ pdd.getAuthor());
          System.out.println("Title of the document is :"+ pdd.getTitle());
          System.out.println("Subject of the document is :"+ pdd.getSubject());

          System.out.println("Creator of the document is :"+ pdd.getCreator());
          System.out.println("Creation date of the document is :"+ pdd.getCreationDate());
          System.out.println("Modification date of the document is :"+ 
             pdd.getModificationDate()); 
          System.out.println("Keywords of the document are :"+ pdd.getKeywords()); 

          //Closing the document 
          document.close();        
       }  
    }
```

For more document properties please refer [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pdfbox/pdfbox_document_properties.htm). HTH.

Comment: I know that，but most of the data I get is null through this method.Thank you all the same.

Comment: It is null probably the pdf you load did not contain the value, do verify that. I have try with this code and it able to retrieve the required value.

Comment: This code can extract documents with these metadata, but the documents I want to extract are less canonical, and the metadata are almost null. Now I've extracted some regular fields from regular expressions